# how do i display image stored in sqlite into tkinter window

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

this is the part that adds the image from an entry box into the database

```
def add_img():
    db=sq.connect('img.db')
    conn=db.cursor()

    with open(str(data.get()),'rb') as f:
        file=f.read()
    with open('yhu.png','wb') as p:
        p.write(f)
    conn.execute(''' INSERT INTO images(name,data)VALUES(?,?)''',(name,file))

    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

and this part is supposed to display the image into the tkiinter window

```
def display():
db=sq.connect('img.db')
conn=db.cursor()
conn.execute('''SELECT * FROM images''')
row=conn.fetchall()

for i in row:

    it=i[1]
    this= open(str(len(i[1])),'wb')
    this.write(base64string.decode('base64'))
    this.close
    imgd=ImageTk.PhotoImage(this)
    panel=tk.Label(image=imgd,height=28,width=30)
    panel.image = imgd
    panel.grid()


db.close()
```

Comment: are you getting errors or what the output you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The `PhotoImage` class and can accept the binary data as a parameter without having to save it to a file:

```
imgd = ImageTk.PhotoImage(data=it)
```

The above assumes that `it` is the binary data from the original image file.